# FixedDataTable: isMounted is deprecated

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

Using FixedDataTable in my react project and im suprised to see the warning below:

```
warning.js:36 Warning: FixedDataTable: isMounted is deprecated. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks.
```

What I've understood is that isMounted is seen as an antipattern [Link](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) so im suprised to see it in the actual source code. Am I missing something here?

```
  _didScrollStop: function _didScrollStop() {
    if (this.isMounted() && this._isScrolling) {
      this._isScrolling = false;
      this.setState({ redraw: true });
      if (this.props.onScrollEnd) {
        this.props.onScrollEnd(this.state.scrollX, this.state.scrollY);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's probably just legacy code that needs updating. The fact that the blog post is dated nearly 2 years ago, and it is still just deprecated (not removed) supports that.

Comment: sure, but i think through webpack upgrade this warning is filling up my console

Comment: Then you have 3 options. 1) Open up the source code where the error is thrown and comment it out (dont recommend). 2) Disable yellow box warnings (config variable, also don't recommend). 3) Use a different package for fixed data tables